# Is there any way to turn off the automatic regeneration of the compiled html page in flex?

Tags: build, flex4

I'm calling a javascript function from a Flex application and it's quite annoying that the page for now where the js-function resides vanishes because every time I make a build and debug the application the page refreshes it's content and all my own code vanishes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your project's `index.template.html` (in `html-template` folder) and place your JavaScript function there.

Comment: Thanks, ha ha, that was easy. Ain't no expert in Flex 4.